# How Can I acess to the attribute X in JSON format?

Tags: java, json

How can I access to the attribute : ***Id,digitalId and title*** in the following JSON format and put them into an arrayList:
 {

```js
{
  "code": 0,
  "data": {
    "count": 4,
    "results": [,
      {
        "id": 61541,
        "digitalId": 0,
        "title": " bigData(2017) #11",

        "textObjects": [{
          "type": "issue_solicit_text",
          "language": "en-us",
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `java` or `javascript`? looks like `java`

Comment: `obj.data.results[0].digitalId`

Comment: AshishRanjan java language

Comment: @dfsq Could you precise the syntaxe for java, please